# How to configure SAP Application Server Enterprise with transaction manager

Tags: transactions, sybase, sap-ase, xa

I'm using a new installation of SAP Application Server Enterprise (ASE) as a database for a IBM WebSphere Application Server Liberty profile server.

When attempting to enlist a one-pahse resource and a two-phase resource
in the same global transaction, deadlock occurs when attempting to use
the second resource. When the server was first configured, the system
did not deadlock for the two-resource transaction and instead emitted
error messages indicating ASE was not configured for XA. The
documentation indicated that in order to enable XA for the ASE, the
following command should be executed using isql:
`sp_configure 'enable DTM', 1`

This command should enable the Distributed Transaction Manager (DTM) and allow the ASE to be XA capable. After executing this command, the DTM
does appear to be enabled and the same code no longer fails saying the
ASE is not configured for XA. However, the code gets a few lines
farther and then deadlocks on execution of a second JDBC PreparedStatement.

After viewing lock information on the ASE and manually killing the
process that is deadlocked the code continues but reports errors, as
would be expected in this case.

According to the ASE documentation, there is nothing else required to
configure the server to be XA capable besides enabling the DTM.
However, given this simple use case which is causing deadlock it appears to be a
configuration issue.

**Example java code:**

```
tran.begin();
Connection con1 = ds1.getConnection(); // Get a one-phase capable
resource
Connection con2 = ds2.getConnection(); // Get a two-phase capable
resource

// Enlist a one-phase resource in the global transaction
PreparedStatement pstmt = con1.prepareStatement("insert into
cities values (?, ?, ?)");
pstmt.setString(1, "CityA");
pstmt.setInt(2, 842);
pstmt.setString(3, "CityB");
pstmt.executeUpdate();

// Enlist a two-phase resource in the global transaction
pstmt = con2.prepareStatement("insert into cities values (?, ?, ?)");
pstmt.setString(1, "CityC");
pstmt.setInt(2, 3252);
pstmt.setString(3, "CityD");

//**************************************************
// Deadlock occurs here, on the executeUpdate() call
pstmt.executeUpdate();
//**************************************************

tran.commit();
```

In short, my question is: how do you configure sybase ASE to allow transaction support besides doing `sp_configure 'enable DTM', 1`?  I can't find anything else in the documentation besides that one command however.